# Ghostscript: Convert PDFs to other filetypes without using the filesystem

Tags: linux, pdf, ghostscript

I want to use the C API to Ghostscript on Linux to convert PDFs to other things: PDFs with fewer pages and images being two examples.

My understanding was by supplying callback functions with gsapi_set_stdio I could read and write data from them.  However from my experimentation and reading, this doesn't seem to be the case.

My motivation for doing this is I will be processing PDFs at scale, and don't want my throughput to be held back by a spinning disk.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stdio API allows you to provide your own replacements for stdin, stdout and stderr, it doesn't affect any activity by the interpreter which doesn't use those.

The pdfwrite device makes extensive use of the filesystem to write temporary files which hold various intermediate portions of the PDF file as it is interpreted, these are then later reassembled into the new PDF file. The temporary files aren't written to stdout or stderr.

There is no way to avoid this behaviour.

Rendering to images again uses the file system, unless you specify stdout as the destination of the bitmap in which case you can use the stdio API call to have stdout redirect elsewhere. If the image is rendered at a high enough resolution then GS will use a display list and again the display list will be stored in a temporary file which will be unaffected by stdio redirection.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I note that poppler does support [reading a PDF document from memory](https://developer.gnome.org/poppler/unstable/PopplerDocument.html#poppler-document-new-from-data) but is GPL only.

Comment: You can use the ram file system (ramfs) to load the PDF into memory with Ghostscript, but I'm very doubtful this would gain you much performance, and would, obviously, use up memory.

Comment: Also, Ghostscript is AGPL or commercial, what kind of licence did you need ?

Comment: Ghostscript can be licensed, linking to GPL code (afaik) means your code also has to be GPL'd.  I will probably go the RAMfs route - if there are lots of random accesses (100ms on a spinning disk),  I see no reason why it wouldn't provide a performance boost.

Comment: Yes Ghostscript has a commercial licence as well as AGPL. You are correct that the Affero GPL, like the regular GPL, would require you to GPL your source. Please note that the ramfs support in Ghostscript is very new, you'll need to use a recent release if you want to try it out.

Comment: Without diskless access, I will probably revert to running Ghostscript in a separate process in server mode for generating PDFs (as that is all I'm using it for).  Is there a flag for server mode, or to use tmpfs?

Comment: We don't understand what you mean by 'server mode'. Temporary files are written in the directory specified by the TMPDIR or TEMP environment variables. So you could set up a mount point to tmpfs and point the environment variables there. See the Ghostscript documentation "/ghostpdl/gs/doc/Use.htm#Environment_variables"

Comment: Thanks for the tip.  As for 'server mode', I refer you to the [Artifex website](http://www.artifex.com/press_release/august-14-2012-3rd-quarter-newsletter.html).

Comment: Ah, well we had assumed this was (like tmpfs) a Linux thing, rather than an interpreter thing. This refers to  using the interpreter in 'job server' mode; you don't close and restart between input files. you just keep feeding in input. The problem with using pdfwrite is knowing when to stop accepting input, and write the output file. Previously the only possible solution was to close the interpreter, now you can start with a different device (eg png), switch to pdfwrite, and when you switch back to the original device, the PDF is produced. The note on the website is specific to PDF production.